# Extract elements literal text using Element Tree

Tags: python, elementtree

I have the following XML with `<Description>` tag having the below text that includes special characters.

```
<branch>
   <Description>
      Here are few steps to make these settings
      1)    Tools &lt;&lt; Internet options 2)  Click on General tab
   </Description>
</branch>
```

Now when I try to retrieve the Description text, I get the following result which has a automatic conversion of `&lt;` to >.
So the code and its result is as follows.

Code -

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET 
tree = ET.parse(inputFile) # copy the above xml into any file and pass the path to inputFile 

    root = tree.getroot()

    for description in root.iter('Description'):
        print(description.text)
```

I need the string literal as is in the Description text tag. How do we get it?

Expected -

```
Here are few steps to make these settings
          1)    Tools >> Internet options 2)    Click on General tab
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `html.escape()` to re-escape the content:

```
import html
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for description in root.iter('Description'):
    print(html.escape(description.text))
```

Result:

```
Here are few steps to make these settings
1)    Tools &lt;&lt; Internet options 2)  Click on General tab
```

Comment: Thanks Cody for this response. It solved my issue. However, my thought was there would be some method within ElementTree that will tackle this situation. Would you by any chance know why does ElementTree convert the raw string.

Comment: @TomThomas There are certain characters that cannot exist in text nodes of XML documents (specifically: `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, `'`) because they would cause issues when parsing. Think about how a `<` character could throw off an XML parser by making it think it's the start of a tag. To get around this problem, those characters are escaped with special entities that safely represent them (in this case, `<` becomes `&lt;`). You just need to "unescape" the characters when you pull them back out of a parsed document.